# Activiti framework - How to change current process instance task via REST API

Tags: activiti

I'm developing a workflow application that communicates with Activiti framework by REST API. 
I'd like to create a tool that allows me to change process instance current task to another one in administrative way. This new task may by anyone in the process flow. 
How can I achive this by REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process definition is static, so you cannot jump to any task.
To go back from T2 to T1, you need to add a sequence flow to your process definition and modify the code of your delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to move a task from one process instance to another, right?

AFAIK, you can't do that with the standard rest api.

That said, I'd review your requirement carefully. A common scenario is that one need to "steal" an already assigned task to someone else because the current owner won't or can't complete it (eg: went on vacation). This can be accomplished by using the "unclaim" method and the explicitly assigning the task to someone else.

If you really need that kind of inter-instance interaction, maybe you can use ad-hoc tasks, which are not tied to a process instance.

Comment: Not exactly what I mean. Let say we have 2 following user tasks (Start > T1 > T2 > End). There is no way back from T2 to T1 on the BPMN diagram. Our IT team needs to have a possibility to move it back to T1 ( or even to anyone step in the diagram) because our business users sometimes require such operations from us  We communicate with Activiti via REST API.

Comment: The REST API does not provide such kind of functionality, and there is a good reason for that: In general, "moving back your pawn" would also require to rollback actions that were performed during the execution of the process steps. You can, however do what you want by doing some direct updates/inserts on the database. I suggest you create a process that does that kind of maintenance, so IT ops can perform those requests in a managed/secure way.